# Tutorial/References for Microsoft's UI Automation

Tags: accessibility, ui-automation

I recently implemented a program using the Microsoft Accessibility API, but have since been told that the new UI Automation has replaced it. Seems like it would be a good investment for next time to learn the newer tool for the job.

So, what are the best references, and hopefully actual tutorials, for programming UI Automation? Specifically, I'm looking for programming "client" applications, i.e. the ones doing the accessing to other program's UI, not just providing access to my own UI.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. Not sure how it happened. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I published a tutorial [An introduction to UI Automation - with Spooky Spirographs](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/06/introduction-to-ui-automation-with.html) that has been quite popular.

Comment: Samuel Jack: Nice article. What msdn tried to convey in pages, you have conveyed it in few lines, yet very simple to understand. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's another tutorial that seems good.
[Automating UI Tests In WPF Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483216.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34038/UI-Automation-Framework-using-WPF also a good station to learn something about ui automation