# Is there an API or class in .NET Framework to detect what you're doing in your desktop like what Windows Narrator does?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there an API or class in .NET Framework to detect what you're doing like what Windows Narrator does? Without the speech? Like when you click or press buttons, it tells us what we're doing.. I just want the text from what Windows Narrator says, or want to know how it knows what we're doing in our desktop, if there's an API that provides information as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API is [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Here's your 30 characters, stack overflow.

Comment: Holy, that made me sound so dumb! Thanks for the rapid answer.

Comment: @user2868984 Modern Windows has extremely large API surface. I don’t know all APIs either. The only reason why I knew about UIA — used it before.

Comment: If I may know, do you know any tutorials or resources for learning UI Automation?

Comment: See answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1559994/126995